# parse.com internationalization (i18n) support in CloudeCode

Tags: javascript, internationalization, parse-platform

i'm playing around with parse push notification and thinking of a good way to implement i18n support for user to user notifications.

my idea:

- for each installation object we store a "language" id
- the message send is always just a message key
- we use a i18n.json with a translations
- whenever a user sends a notification, we go through all defined languages, and create for each language a query for recipient with language.
- for each language we have to grab the message and replace all placeholder values

It works fine, but i think there is room for optimization. I haven't done any performance test to see how it works in production.

i'm currently running a setup with 10 languages. in case the recipient uses the same language on all his devices, 9 out of 10 Parse.Push.send({}); operations are actually not necessary. But i have no idea right now how to avoid them.

```
var translations = require('cloud/translations.js');
var languages = ["en", "de"];


Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToUser", function(request, response) {

    var recipientUserId = request.params.recipient;
    var message = request.params.message;
    var key = request.params.messageKey;
    var senderName = request.params.name;

    var language;

    var translationsObj = translations["translations"];

    for(var i = 0; i < languages.length; i++){

        language = languages[i];

        pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        pushQuery.equalTo("userId", recipientUserId);
        pushQuery.equalTo("language", language);

        var alertMessage = message;

        if(translationsObj[key] && translationsObj[key][language]){
            console.log("found translation for " + key + " (" + language + ")");
            var rawMessage = translationsObj[key][language];
            alertMessage = rawMessage.split("[[senderName]]").join(senderName);
        }

        Parse.Push.send({
                where: pushQuery,
            data: {alert: alertMessage}
            }).then(function() {
                console.log("successfully send push '" + alertMessage + "' to " + recipientUserId + "")
            }, function(error) {
        });
    }
    response.success("Push was sent successfully"); 
});
```